# Overriding sendEvent in custom UIApplication to detect hardware keyboard event

Tags: ios, uiapplication

I am developing an iPad app that needs to read input from a hardware keyboard.  A primary user will be touching the screen normally while another user controls certain aspects of the app from a nearby Bluetooth keyboard that is paired with the iPad.

Overriding the **keyCommands** property in UIResponder has worked perfectly until now.  But when we moved the app to Cocos2d (which uses its own responder chain) all the **keyCommands** stuff stopped working.

I tried subclassing UIApplication with an overridden **sendEvent:** method, something as simple as this:

```
#import "MyUIApplication.h"

@implementation MyUIApplication  // subclass of UIApplication

-(void)sendEvent:(UIEvent *)event {
    [super sendEvent:event];
    NSLog(@"Event detected");
}
```

As far as I can tell, this successfully detects all events *except* for hardware keyboard events, which appear to be totally ignored.  Is there some way to detect these events without using **keyCommands** and **UIKeyCommand**s?